# How to Increase alexa skills kit Developer JSON file size limit of 1MB

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

As the title suggests how do I increase the file size limit of the Alexa skill kit developer JSON file size limit of 1 MB .

I am making an amazon Alexa skill and have a LOT of utterances, the size of the JSON file that I wish to use is around 3MB.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've run into limits in the past, and identified that the problem was the web IDE. I didn't have any problems after witching to using the Alexa CLI for uploading my data instead.